# AssemblyInfo version information asterisks

Tags: c#, .net

It says in AssemblyInfo.cs for C# projects that it's possible to specify version information with `*`

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I changed it to this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*.*")]
```

and this is the error I get from the compiler:

```
error CS0647: Error emitting 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute -- 'The version specified '1.0.*.*' is invalid'
warning CS1607: Assembly generation -- The version '1.0.*.*' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format
```

How does (does it even?) it work?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Syntax (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx)) for "automatic" build number can be:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]
```

or:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

<kbd>*</kbd> means *after this everything is automatic*. You can't have automatic build  number and fixed revision number then this syntax isn't correct:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*.0")]
```

For the `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` you cannot use the <kbd>*</kbd> special character so you have to provide a full and valid version number. Please note that if you **do not provide** an `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` then you'll get the right `FileVersionInfo` automatically (with the same version of `AssemblyVersionAttribute`). You need to specify that attribute only if you need to set a different version.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The file version on the DLL is always 1.0.0.0 and the product version on the DLL is either 1.0.* or 1.0.0.* ?

Comment: what about <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.#rev.*")>, it also shows same invalid error

Comment: @shyamnathan yes, each part must be a 16 bit unsigned integer - 1 so you can't use anything else than `*` (and only in `x.y.*` or `x.y.z.*` form). Of course unless it's kind of placeholder and you apply some sort of preprocessing (useful if you do not have a shared assembly info and you want to keep version aligned across different assemblies). Error message is pretty generic, any invalid version number will give that message whichever is the reason.

Comment: <Assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.#rev.*")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.#rev")> and the assembly file version does not show any errors, guess I'll stick to 2.0.0.* for assembly version and 2.0.0 for assembly file version which doesn't show any errors and thank you.

Comment: It might be worth noting that it does not auto increment *by one* with every build as you might expect, but makes some numbers up (random? time dependent?) -- so you can just use it to tell versions apart, but not to tell which is the most recent build (at least not at first glance)

Comment: @Tommy in form X.Y.Z.* build number is random, in form X.Y.* revision is number of days from a reference date and build is number of seconds from midnight.

Answer (score 34):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")] 
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

just remember to comment the AssemblyFileVersion line, otherwise the automatically generated assembly version will always be "1.0.0.0".

Comment: the automatically generated assembly version will always be "1.0.0.0", this happens to my solution.

Comment: Let me suggest that you `edit` your answer and add that information as well. "it may not work as expected" does not exactly explain why the OP should follow this suggestion, compared to the answer that [Adriano](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10229738/238902) gave.

Comment: yes, commenting out the second line was required in my case too for the autonumbering to work

Comment: In VS2010 and prior versions, attribute `AssemblyFileVersion` does *not* support wildcards. If `AssemblyFileVersion` is *not* explicitly set, it takes its value from the `AssemblyVersion` attribute. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15506131/1497596) for more details.

Answer (score 12):

So why does the supplied comment say

```
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

but builds generate CS8357?
Somebody didn't get the memo.

```
Work around:

 1. Close all open documents
 2. In the Solution Explorer, right-click the Project and select Unload Project
 3. In the Solution Explorer, right-click the Project (now marked as unavailable) and select Edit to access the `.CSPROJ` file
 4. In the opened window, find `<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>` and change it to `<Deterministic>false</Deterministic>`
 5. Save the file and ensure that the edit window is closed
 6. In the Solution Explorer, right-click the Project and select Reload Project

Your build (should then) work. :)
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this over 100 times.  Perfect.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, using `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("x.y.z.*")]`, `Patch` shouldn't be automatically numbered. Eg:

> [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.*")]

Using '*' in `AssemblyVersion` is good, but follow seemver.org we should use `*` for the `revision` part from version structure `<major version>.<minor version>.<build number>.<revision>`).

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
>
> MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
>
> PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

Comment: That format is no good. [The auto generated revision number is defined as the number of seconds since midnight, divided by 2.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks) So if you happen to build your assembly earlier in the day than the last time, you will actually decrease the revision number.

Answer (score 0):

I have using the '*' in the version for add more information about the application version, build(date) and revision(hours in day)
In my code, I use:

Fragment from AssemblyInfo.cs

```
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

**In constructor or load event**

```
 Version? ver = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
 if (ver != null)
 {
     var dt = ver.ToDateTime();
     verLabel.Content = string.Format("ver.{0}.0.0.{1} ({2:yy/MM/dd HH:mm})", ver.Major, ver.Minor, dt);
 }

 public static class VersionExtension
 {
     public static DateTime ToDateTime(this Version ver)
     {
         var dt = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
         //plus days
         dt = dt.AddDays(ver.Build);
         //plus seconds
         dt = dt.AddSeconds(ver.Revision * 2);
         return dt; 
     }
 }
```

I use 'Build' value to find the day that the project is compiled, and 'Revision' to get the precise hour.

For determinism, use this

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
    <Deterministic>False</Deterministic>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The right tag is **Deterministic**!