# CS1607: The version specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format in .NET

Tags: .net, warnings, wildcard, assemblyversionattribute

I am trying to set my `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` attributes in my project like so:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("3.0.*")]
```

but I get this warning:

> **CS1607:** Assembly generation -- The version '3.0.*' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal
>   'major.minor.build.revision' format

On the `AssemblyVersionAttribute Class` page at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) is the following:

> You can specify all the values or you can accept the default build
>   number, revision number, or both by using an asterisk (*). For
>   example, [assembly:AssemblyVersion("2.3.25.1")] indicates 2 as the
>   major version, 3 as the minor version, 25 as the build number, and 1
>   as the revision number. **A version number such as
>   [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")] specifies 1 as the major version,
>   2 as the minor version, and accepts the default build and revision
>   numbers.** A version number such as
>   [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")] specifies 1 as the major
>   version, 2 as the minor version, 15 as the build number, and accepts
>   the default revision number.

Note the bold section. Does anyone know why `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.0.*")]` (from my project) is not valid, but `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]` (from the MSDN example) is valid?

In particular, I am curious to know if I can start with a non-zero major number, as the application that I am writing is version 3 of the program.

UPDATE >>> Sorry, this does seem to be answered in the other post... please vote to close it, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AssemblyInfo version information asterisks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229711/assemblyinfo-version-information-asterisks)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You're assuming that the problem is with this line:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.0.*")]
```

when it is actually with this one:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("3.0.*")]
```

Like [the accepted answer to the question that you say is not a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229738/366904) says:

> For the `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` you cannot use the * special character so you have to provide a full and valid version number.

That `*` syntax works *only* with the `AssemblyVersion` attribute. It doesn't work with the `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute.

There are two workarounds to achieve the results you probably desire here:

1. Simply omit the `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute altogether. That will cause the assembly file version information to be automatically divined from the `AssemblyVersion` attribute (which is the one that *does* support the `*` syntax).
2. Break out the big guns and install the [Build Version Increment add-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22c5f085-d1be-44a3-b5a4-4710a467b972), which offers you more version incrementing options than you can shake a stick at.

Comment: Thanks, you are quite right... somehow I totally missed that line in the other post, I then came back here to delete this post, but you had already answered it, so I can't. I've voted to close it instead.

Comment: An update on this, AssemblyFileVersion accepts the `*` character in .NET 4 onward.

Comment: @Vince It didn't work in Visual Studio 2010, whether targeting .NET 4 or any other version. Do you mean that it works with VS 2012? This is related to the version of the compiler/linker, not the target framework.

Comment: @CodyGray My apologies you're correct. I'm too busy in VS land ignoring what's under the covers :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.assemblyfileversionattribute(v=vs.100).aspx       "wild cards are NOT supported"